# jQuery FullCalendar, Jscript Runtime error

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

This is my code, keep prompt me message "Microsoft Jscript Runtime error: Object expected"

What wrong with my code?? Help

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
<style type='text/css'> 

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #calendar {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

</style>
```

Comment: Poorly worded question, and what to the iphone / ios tags have to do with this issue, no one will see this question when it has the wrong tags.

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: ok....i re-post...since i am beginner..sorry